# QT большая задержка в RTSP стриме при использовании стандарта H264

Tags: c++, qt, mediaplayer, rtsp

Написал небольшой код для отображения видео с камер и столкнулся с проблемой задержек при трансляции, растующих в арифметической прогрессии.  На камере используется стандарт H264 для кодирования, в случае MJPEG проблема отсутствует
Во время работы ПО отслеживается 90-100% нагрузка на процессор.

```
_player.setMedia(QUrl(URI));
QVideoWidget* videoWidget = new QVideoWidget();
_ui->videoLayout->addWidget(videoWidget);
_player.setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
_player.play();
```

Player - объект класса QMediaPlayer. При просмотре потока в других ПО, эта задержка так же отсутствует.
Как я понял, на разных системах используется разный бэк для работы в аудио или видео. Мной используется система elementary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два источника задержек, которые вносит сама технология H264.

1. Задержка, связянная с частотой появления в потоке ключевых кадров - отобрачать поток можно начать только с ключевого кадра, так что декодер будет всегда ждать его появления.
2. Задержка, вызванная буферизацией данных, причем иногда возможность конфигурирования этого буфера запрятана очень глубоко.

Очевидно, что оба этих источника поддаются коррекции путем настройки.

Есть еще одна беда, которая может все испортить - это недостаток системных ресурсов. Судя по вашим симптомам (прогрессирование проблемы со временем и полная загрузка процессора) - это ваш кейс.

Вероятно, *другой софт, который не тормозит,* использует аппаратное декодирование видео.

Беглый поиск показывает, что в Qt по этой теме все более-менее может [заработать на QML](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/blob/master/examples/QMLPlayer/qml/QMLPlayer/VideoCodec.qml), а для обычного приложения придется использовать gstreamer / libavcodec.

Comment: Другой софт, который используется - vlc, например, и собственный веб-интерфейс камеры.
Просмотрел запросы обеих ПО на RTSP сервер, кроме 3 моментов, остальное совпадает:
1. Между запросами SETUP и PLAY идет отправка 8 пакетов, структура которых
0000   | bc 74 d7 80 1a 5d 00 ce f2 a0 0a 85 08 00 45 00
0010   | 00 20 99 39 40 00 40 11 fe df ac 10 a5 35 ac 10
0020   | a5 5d 8f 03 7d 3b 00 0c a2 d1 ce fa ed fe
Как я понял какой то синхропакет.
2. Для поля Range в запросе PLAY в случае vlc используетс npt=0.000, а мое ПО использует npt=now
3. С каждым запр. мое ПО отправляет поле Date.

Comment: исходя из моего небольшого понимания протокола, это не может повлиять на увеличивающееся расхождение по времени, поэтому остается кейс только с аппаратной частью. подправьте, если не прав

Comment: Чтобы вас "поправить" мне придется провести достаточно большую работу - найти спецификацию протокола и сличить с вашим дампам. Но в данный момент я занят.

Если моя гипотеза верна, у вас альтернативные плееры не должны так обильно жрать ресурсы, как это делает ваше приложение.

Ну и дурацкий вариант - а вы точно релиз собрали и запускаете?